Relationship among event.clientX,Y, event.pageX,Y, window.scrollX,Y to subpixel accuracy
I'd like to know the x,y location of my MouseEvents,
in page coordinates and in viewport (aka client) coordinates,
as accurately as possible (definitely subpixel accuracy).
See here for definitions of the coordinate systems.
I don't see this mentioned in any MDN docs, but I notice (in chrome and firefox):

event.pageX,Y always seem to always be exact integers
event.clientX,Y always seems to always be exact integers
window.scrollX,Y is typically non-integer

(To be more precise, window.scrollX,Y may be non-integer when scrolled and browser zoom is >100% or not a power of 2; and it's always non-integer when scrolled and browser zoom is not a power of 2)
That implies that the following logical relationships among the three
coordinate pair values are often inexact;
they must be off by as much as 1/2 pixel, depending on how far away
window.scrollX,Y is from an integer:

event.pageX,Y == event.clientX,Y + window.scrollX,Y  (approximately)
event.clientX,Y == event.pageX,Y - window.scrollX,Y  (approximately)
window.scrollX,Y == event.pageX,Y - event.clientX,Y  (approximately)

Given all this, in my mouse event handler, what's my best
estimate of the event's "real" pageX,Y and clientX,Y, to subpixel
accuracy?
Does the event object contain one of those integer pairs
exactly in some sense, and the other pair rounded?
Or are they both rounded?  (They can't both be right.)
Focusing on just the Y parts, I imagine the best estimate might be:
  const accurate_pageY = event.pageY;
  const accurate_clientY = event.pageY - window.scrollY;
  /* and ignore event.clientY */

Or maybe:
  const accurate_pageY = event.clientY + window.scrollY;
  const accurate_clientY = event.clientY;
  /* and ignore event.pageY */

Or, maybe I could take the average of the previous two estimates:
  const accurate_pageY = (event.pageY + (event.clientY + window.scrollY)) / 2;
  const accurate_clientY = ((event.pageY - window.scrollY) + event.clientY) / 2;

I hope it's obvious that this matters, for smooth/faithful response to the user's mouse motions and gestures.
